# Getting weather and cycling data (yr.no, oslobysykkel)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, postgresql, docker

What I am trying to do, is to get weather data, data about bike trips and populate the postgresql database in order to be able to work with this data from Power BI/Tableau/any other tool.

I have two different data sources. The first of them is yr.no API, which I am using to access weather data. The second one is oslobysykkel.no, from where I get data related to bike trips.

The goal is to have this initial load done with docker containers and azure blob storages, as I would like to learn more about them. But that would be the second stage. I have not really done any  "ETL-ish" processing in python before, so I would love to get some feedback from you related to my code and flow.

The current structure looks like that:

[image]

I am not really sure if that looks OK but I was thinking about having two different docker containers(one for extract/process part and the second one for loading the data to postgresql.

The first one to be created is calendar table:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import os
"""
Simple script, using pandas library to create a date table. One time job.
"""
local_path_processed = os.environ.get('LOCAL_PATH_PROCESSED')
start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2030-12-31'
"""
#Additional settings for pandas to make printouts more clear in the console, it's getting easier to debug.  
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',12)
desired_width=320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
"""

def create_date_table(start_date, end_date):
  df = pd.DataFrame({"date_hour": pd.date_range(start_date, end_date,freq='H')})
  df["date"] = df.date_hour.dt.date
  df["hour"] = df.date_hour.dt.hour
  df["day"] = df.date_hour.dt.day
  df["day_name"] = df.date_hour.dt.day_name()
  df["week"] = df.date_hour.dt.weekofyear
  df["quarter"] = df.date_hour.dt.quarter
  df["year"] = df.date_hour.dt.year
  df["year_half"] = (df.quarter + 1) // 2
  return df

timestampStr = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")
"""
Create date table
"""
date_df = create_date_table(start_date,end_date)
"""
Add date id, ETL timestamp and write down data
"""
date_df["date_id"] = date_df.date_hour.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d%H')).astype(int)
date_df["etl_timestamp"] = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")
date_df_sorted = date_df[ ['date_id'] + [ col for col in date_df.columns if col != 'date_id' ] ]
date_df_sorted.to_csv(local_path_processed + 'date_table.csv',index=False)
```

Table with bike trips. First, I am getting raw files using selenium(one file is one month) and then I am doing some simple transformations.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os
import time
"""
#Additional settings for pandas to make printouts more clear in the console, it's getting easier to debug.  
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',12)
desired_width=320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
"""

"""
Get raw data using selenium and oslo bysykkel website. It takes some time to download data depending on your internet connectione.
Therefore I have used time(sleep) in order to avoid running further processing on partial data.
"""
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

local_path_raw = os.environ.get('LOCAL_PATH_RAW')
local_path_processed = os.environ.get('LOCAL_PATH_PROCESSED')

remote_path = "https://developer.oslobysykkel.no/apne-data/historisk"

def download_data(remote_path, local_path, options,month_range):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': local_path}}
    driver.execute("send_command", params)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(remote_path)
    for month in range(1,month_range):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div/div/article/ul[1]/li[{}]/div/div[2]/a[2]/button'.format(month)).click()

op = Options()
op.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
op.add_experimental_option("prefs",{
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

download_data(remote_path, local_path_raw, op, 15)
time.sleep(30)
"""
Processing part:
  Merging all raw csv files into one dataframe.
  Processing of dataframe, adding all columns that I use for the reporting layer.
"""
os.chdir(local_path_raw)
counter = 0
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    if os.stat(local_path_raw+"\{}".format(file)).st_size <= 264:
        pass
    else:
        if counter == 0:
            bike_trip_df = pd.read_csv(file)
        else:
            bike_trip_df.append(pd.read_csv(file))
        counter += 1

def process_df(dataframe):
    dataframe['bike_trip_id'] = dataframe.index
    dataframe['started_at_floor'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['started_at']).dt.floor(freq='H')
    dataframe['ended_at_floor'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['ended_at']).dt.floor(freq='H')
    dataframe['date_id'] = dataframe.apply(lambda x: list(pd.date_range(x['started_at_floor'], x['ended_at_floor'], freq="1H")), axis='columns')
    dataframe = dataframe.explode('date_id')
    dataframe['date_id'] = dataframe['date_id'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H')
    return dataframe

bike_trip_df = process_df(bike_trip_df)
bike_trip_df.to_csv(local_path_processed+"bike_trip.csv",sep=";")
```

Then a table with weather observations. I am getting hourly data for each day. YYYYMMDDHH is also a key that I want to use in my data model to connect everything.  In the next stage, I would like to use azure blob storages instead of local memory, so that I can create those independent docker images as well:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import parser
import os
"""
#Additional settings for pandas to make printouts more clear in the console, it's getting easier to debug.  
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',12)
desired_width=320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
"""
start_date = os.environ.get('START_DATE_WEATHER')
end_date = os.environ.get('END_DATE_WEATHER')
local_path_processed = os.environ.get('LOCAL_PATH_PROCESSED')
def get_date_range(begin, end):
    beginDate = parser.parse(begin)
    endDate =  parser.parse(end)
    delta = endDate-beginDate
    numdays = delta.days + 1
    dayList = [datetime.strftime(beginDate + timedelta(days=x), '%m-%d-%Y') for x in range(0, numdays)]
    return dayList

list_of_dates = get_date_range(start_date,end_date)

def call_api(list_of_dates):
    row_values = []
    for date in list_of_dates:
        try:
            raw_json = requests.get('https://www.yr.no/api/v0/locations/1-72837/observations/{}'.format(date)).json()
            for day in raw_json.get('historical').get('days'):
                for hour in day.get('hours'):
                    row_object = {}
                    for key, value in hour.items():
                        try:
                            row_object[key] = next(iter(value.values()))
                        except:
                            row_object[key] = value
                    for key, value in row_object.items():
                        try:
                            if len(value) == 0:
                                row_object[key] = None
                        except:
                            pass
                    row_values.append(row_object)
        except:
            pass
    return process_dataframe(row_values)

def process_dataframe(row_values):
    df = pd.DataFrame(row_values)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
    df['date_id'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d%H'))
    df['rush_hour'] = df.date_id.apply(
        lambda x: "Yes" if (int(x[:-2]) in range(6, 10) or int(x[-2:])) in range(15, 19) else "No")
    return df

observation_df = call_api(list_of_dates)
observation_df["etl_timestamp"] = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")
observation_df.to_csv(local_path_processed + "weather_observation.csv",sep=";")
```

And finally, I am writing data to three different tables in my postgresql database.

```
import psycopg2.extras
import pandas as pd
import io
import psycopg2
import os

base_path = os.environ.get('BASE_PATH')
database = os.environ.get('DATABASE')
username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')
host = os.environ.get('HOST')

def db_connect (db_parm, username_parm, host_parm, pw_parm):
    credentials = {'host': host_parm, 'database': db_parm, 'user': username_parm, 'password': pw_parm}
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**credentials,cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    conn.autocommit = True
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print ("Connected Successfully to DB: " + str(db_parm) + "@" + str(host_parm))
    return conn, cur

def db_insert(filename, table_name, file_path, conn, cur):
    dataframe = pd.read(file_path+filename)
    output = io.StringIO()
    dataframe.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
    output.seek(0)
    copy_query = "COPY {} FROM STDOUT csv DELIMITER '\t' NULL ''  ESCAPE '\\' HEADER ".format(table_name)  # Replace your table name in place of mem_info
    cur.copy_expert(copy_query, output)
    conn.commit()


conn, cur = db_connect(database, username, host, password)

db_insert("filename", "date", base_path, conn, cur)
db_insert("filename", "weather_observation", base_path, conn, cur)
db_insert("filename", "bike_trip", base_path, conn, cur)
```

Thank you in advance for any feedback & suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

### Shadowing

You declare these globals:

```
start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2030-12-31'
```

and also these parameters:

```
def create_date_table(start_date, end_date):
```

That is confusing; the local parameters will take priority. One way to distinguish the two is to capitalize the global constants, which is standard anyway.

### snake_case

`timestampStr` should be `timestamp_str`.

### Selenium

I don't know a lot about the website, but a brief visit makes it seem like this is simple enough for you to avoid Selenium - which tries to emulate a browser - and do direct HTTP using the Requests library plus BeautifulSoup, which will be much more efficient.

### pathlib

This:

```
os.stat(local_path_raw+"\{}".format(file))
```

will be simplified using `pathlib.Path(local_path_raw)`.

### Exception swallowing

This:

```
    except:
        pass
```

is extremely dangerous. It will prevent user break (Ctrl+C) from working, and will hide anything going wrong in that section of the code - even if it's a critical failure. At the absolute least, `except Exception` instead of `except`, and ideally print what's gone wrong.

### os.environ.get

You don't seem to be treating these parameters as optional; you don't provide defaults. So this will create some failures later than they should occur. Use `[]` instead to move the failure up to a point where it's more obvious that a parameter is missing.

### Autocommit

Since you've enabled this, why do you also

```
conn.commit()
```

?